# Unable to show "circle-open-dot" in scatter plot using plotly js

Tags: plotly, plotly.js

I am trying to use different types of markers provided by [ploltly js](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#scattergl-marker-symbol) (type: scattergl). But only vanilla markers like normal square, cirlcle and diamond are working with `scattergl`. Please check the code below:

#### HTML:

```xml
<head>
    <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='myDiv-scattergl'></div>
    <div id='myDiv-scatter'></div>
</body>
```

#### JS:

```js
var trace1 = {
  x : [0,1,2],
  y: [6,7,8],
  mode: 'markers',
  marker: {

  size: [20, 40, 20],
    symbol: 300
  },
  type: "scattergl"
};

var data = [trace1];

var layout = {
  title: 'Scatter-gl Plot '
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv-scattergl', data, layout);

data[0].type = "scatter"
layout.title = "Scatter Plot";
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv-scatter', data, layout);
```

#### Output:

[Plots produced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFSVd.png)

With `scattergl`, *circle-open-dot* is not being rendered. Am I missing something? Please help.

Comment: Fix the link – error 404

Answer (score 0):

Just use `symbol: "circle-open-dot"` instead of `symbol: 300`.

```js
var trace1 = {
  x : [0,1,2],
  y: [6,7,8],
  mode: 'markers',
  marker: {
    size: [20, 40, 20],
    symbol: "circle-open-dot"
  },
  type: "scattergl"
};

var data = [trace1];

var layout = {
  title: 'Scatter-gl Plot '
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv-scattergl', data, layout);

data[0].type = "scatter"
layout.title = "Scatter Plot";
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv-scatter', data, layout);
```

```html
<head>
    <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='myDiv-scattergl'></div>
    <div id='myDiv-scatter'></div>
</body>
```